# addEventListener STILL firing multiple times (even with same name callback)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

The below code just applies an event to multiple DOM elements. Since this set of code will be called multiple times, the events will be applied to the same element multiple times.

I avoided having them be assigned again (by using the same callback function instead of anonymous functions), but they are still being applied and fired several times. What am I not seeing here?

```
//apply delete event listener to all list items
function applyListener(){
    let delBtnS = document.querySelectorAll(".toDoList li span")
    let checkOff = document.querySelectorAll(".toDoList li");

    //separate function won't have event applied multiple times
    let applyCompleted = function(){
        console.log("Apply has been pressed");
    }

    let applyDelete = function(event){
        console.log("Delete has been pressed");
    }

    //checkOff
    for (let item of Array.from(checkOff)){ 
        item.addEventListener("click", applyCompleted);
    }


    //delete button
        for (let btn of Array.from(delBtnS)){
        btn.addEventListener("click", applyDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean, when you  click the span it hits applyCompleted and applyDelete?

Comment: @RicardoPontual No, I understand I can prevent that from happening with .stopPropagation()

The issue is that each one is firing multiple times even though it shouldn't be

Comment: this is strange, because if you attach an equal event (same signature), this event will be discarded, as attests here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners

Answer (score 1):

It's because event [propagates](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php) up the DOM tree, means a parent node will react to events even if they happen at it's children. You need to use [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```
let applyDelete = function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); // click on <span> won't travel to it's parent <li>
    console.log("Delete has been pressed");
}
```